# Is it better to organize css by property or by selector

Tags: css, sass, structure

In process of developing a site, I have stumbled on two ways on how to organize my css (it's actully scss). The first one is by groupinng my selectors/combinators around a property, in this way (as in the example bellow) I belive I am avoiding duplication of properties. (More after the example)

```
.footer {
  background-color: $primary;
  & a,
  & i,
  & h2,
  & p {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  & a,
  & p {
    @include font(20, 300);
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  & h2 {
    @include font(24, 700);
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}
```

In the second way, I'd group my properties inside elements that have the same style (as in the example bellow).

I believe this way makes more sense, since you're referring to each block of properties as styles to elements that look alike. But the first case seems to offer a bit more visual clarity. Are there arguments on which way is better and which one provides better organization and less mind effort in understanding the code?

```
.footer {
  background-color: $primary;
  & a,
  & p {
    @include font(20, 300);
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  & h2 {
    @include font(24, 700);
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  & i {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I try to do as minimum as possible to directly set rules directly to html balise as I find it confusing (just my opinion though).
Maybe for some resets of rules to apply on the whole site some times.

So I would go with the first approch, but using classes instead (with meaningfull names):

```
.footer {
  background-color: $primary;
  & .text-white {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  & .text-medium {
    @include font(20, 300);
  }
  & .title {
    @include font(24, 700);
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}
```

This also reduce the CSS code needed as a same balise can have multiple classes.

Maybe some persons would say it force you to edit your HTML to add all the classes needed but I find it easier to maintain that way.